# Entity Framework problem with reducing projection

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I've been working on improving performance for our .NET core API with EF 5.0.11 by reducing the projection of our queries, but I'm currently stuck with the following scenario:

I improved the projection of the queries like this:

```
var employeeEmailQuery = context.Employee
                .Where(e => e.Active == true)
                .Select(e => new EmployeeEmailView
                {
                    Name = e.FullName,
                    Email = e.Email
                });
```

This reduces the select query to just the two columns I need instead of a SELECT * on 80+ columns in the database.

In my database, I also have columns with translated descriptions. It looks like this:
[image]

What I would like to do is select the relevant translated description, based on the current culture, so I added the following code:

```
 var culture = CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture;
 var employeeEmailQuery = context.Employee
            .Where(e => e.Active == true)
            .Select(e => new EmployeeEmailView
            {
                Name = e.FullName,
                Email = e.Email,
                this.SetDescription(e, culture);
            });
```

The SetDescription method checks the culture and picks the correct column to set a Description property in the EmployeeEmailView. However, by adding this code, the query is now once again doing a SELECT *, which I don't want.

Does anybody have an idea on how to dynamically include a select column using EF without rewriting everything into raw SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using SQL server 2014

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to use an [Interceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) to modify the query, or dynamically generate the EF IQueryable with Expressions.